How do I specify the size of the entire Carousel component of ShadCN UI?
I currently have the following React component:
"use client";
import Autoplay from "embla-carousel-autoplay";
import { Card, CardContent } from "@/components/ui/card";
import {
    Carousel,
    CarouselContent,
    CarouselItem,
    CarouselNext,
    CarouselPrevious,
} from "@/components/ui/carousel";
import { ThemeToggle } from "@/components/theme-toggle";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-screen">
            <div className="flex-grow max-w-max text-center">
                <Link href="/login">Login</Link>
                <ThemeToggle />
                <Carousel
                    opts={{
                        loop: true,
                        align: "center",
                    }}
                    plugins={[
                        Autoplay({
                            delay: 5000,
                        }),
                    ]}
                    className="w-full max-w-xl"
                >
                    <CarouselContent>
                        {Array.from({ length: 5 }).map((_, index) => (
                            <CarouselItem key={index} className="pt-1">
                                <div className="p-1">
                                    <Card>
                                        <CardContent className="flex items-center justify-center p-6">
                                            <span className="text-3xl font-semibold">
                                                {index + 1}
                                            </span>
                                        </CardContent>
                                    </Card>
                                </div>
                            </CarouselItem>
                        ))}
                    </CarouselContent>
                    <CarouselPrevious />
                    <CarouselNext />
                </Carousel>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

I want to style the Carousel component so that it has a width of 50% of the page, and a height of like 32REM. However, I cannot for the life of me find a way to do it. When I make the Carousel component bigger, the content doesn't scale, but auto-scaling the content doesn't make it bigger either. Does anybody know how I can modify the size of the Carousel and its content?

I managed to achieve what you were trying to do applying flex, justify center and items center to CarouselItem and. To set the height I set it on the div wrapping the Card component and to set the width I set it on the Card component itself.
Here's my .tsx code:
import { Card, CardContent } from './ui/card';
import {
  Carousel,
  CarouselContent,
  CarouselItem,
  CarouselNext,
  CarouselPrevious,
} from './ui/carousel';
import Autoplay from 'embla-carousel-autoplay';

    export default function News() {
      return (
        <Carousel
          className='mt-[2rem]'
          opts={{ loop: true }}
          plugins={[Autoplay({ delay: 4000 })]}
        >
          <CarouselContent>
            {Array.from({ length: 5 }).map((_, index) => (
              <CarouselItem
                key={index}
                className='flex justify-center items-center'
              >
                <div className='p-1 w-[1200px]'>
                  <Card className='h-[400px]'>
                    <CardContent className='flex items-center justify-center p-6'>
                      <span className='text-4xl font-semibold'>{index + 1}</span>
                    </CardContent>
                  </Card>
                </div>
              </CarouselItem>
            ))}
          </CarouselContent>
          <CarouselPrevious className='absolute left-[2rem] top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 z-10' />
          <CarouselNext className='absolute right-[2rem] top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 z-10' />
        </Carousel>
      );
    }



